# Hiding elements with negative margin

Tags: css

I have read (actually here on SO, but cannot find the post at the moment) about a way to hide elements with negative margins.

I recall, that the answer contained a deep explanation on why to do this, and the benefits over other methods (`visibility: hidden; position: absolute;`, `display: none`). And yes, the method provided a way to remove the element out of the document flow (possibly hackish, not valid).

Have I been dreaming about this or there is such a way? If there is, then yes, I would love the little in-depth explanation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To my knowledge, the only way to remove something from the document flow is using `position:absolute`. You can definitely hide elements with a negative margin, but it will still be in the flow.

Comment: Did it come from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989930/css-negative-margin

Comment: @Diodeus, checked it before asking, there is nothing about hiding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to hide block level elements like a div, or just the text on a link that's got a background image, for instance. If it's the second item, the CSS you're looking for is text-indent. I've used it in the past like this:

```
a.button {
  /* .button is a for instance class name */
  text-indent: -9999px
}
```

This will leave the block level element (the a tag) and any background you've placed on it, in the document flow, but will move the text off screen. This is a technique I've used in the past, but be careful of the text you're hiding--the search engines look at this as a quasi-black hat technique. Just make sure the hidden text doesn't look like keyword stuffing or obvious spam terms and you'll be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh snap! It could be this and not the margin. *accepting this, because it's the "closest" answer*

Answer (score 2):

Using negative margins is generally considered a more "accessible" way of hiding elements. Absolute positioning OR floating will remove it from the document flow.

This article summarizes several image replacement techniques.

http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/

HTH!

Comment: "Generally considered" – by whom? Accessibility means that content is *accessible* to everyone, not that superfluous content will be available to users with disabilities but not others. Use a screenreader and see that approach falling apart.

Comment: @PointedEars By web design thought leaders and accessibility experts who have tested various image replacement techniques with screen readers. Read the article I shared.

Comment: You have shared the article, but you have not read it. If you had, you would have observed that *all* these cargo-cultish approaches have issues. And as for "web design thought leaders and accessibility experts", you must be kidding me.

Answer (score 2):

Either you have been dreaming or you have become a victim of cargo cult coding.  The obvious disadvantage of excessive negative margins is that you are relying on a maximum window size.  (Excessive negative `text-indent` also has that problem and others.) Anything larger and the element becomes visible again. Add to that that it is nowhere specified what to do with negative margins of that magnitude.

Only with `display: none` you can remove an element reliably (as if it was not there).  Absolute positioning takes an element out of the normal flow, which is not the same as removing it.